# jQuery variable inside element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a datepicker using jQuery, i retrieve the input id's for the inputs that need a datepicker through user input. Those id's are stored in an  `array` that loops through an  `foreach`.

Now i want to pass those id's inside the element selector to add the right attributes, currently I am using variables for that but i doubt that this is a valid way for doing this,

Any help is appreciated :)

```
 foreach ($date_picker_input_id as $input_id) 
    {
        if (!$('input[id='$input_id']').val()) 
        {
           $('input[id='$input_id']').val('<?= date('d-m-Y'); ?>');
           $('input[id='$input_id']').datepicker(datepicker_settings);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given that you apply the same settings to all elements, what's the point of the loop? It makes more sense to give them all the same `class` and just apply the settings to that class. Also note that CSS should be applied in an external stylesheet, not inline and certainly not through JS

Comment: @David -can you review and correct your posted code? At the moment it is not clear what is php and what is javascript.

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: you are sometimes missing php open and close tag

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing php tags :**

try this :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['int']);
            $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: "<?= $url_icon_calendar; ?>",
            buttonText: "[:datepicker_title:]"
            });

          var datepicker_settings = { dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' };
          <?php
          foreach ($date_picker_input_id as $input_id) 
          {
              if (!$('input[id='$input_id']').val()) {
          ?>
              $('input[id='$input_id']').val('<?= date('d-m-Y'); ?>');
          <?php } ?>
              $('input[id='$input_id']').datepicker(datepicker_settings);
              $('input[id='$input_id']').css({'float': 'left', 'width': '50%'});

              $('img.ui-datepicker-trigger').css({
              'width': '22px', 'height': '22px', 'float': 'left', 'position':'relative','left':'-24px','top':'-1px', 'opacity':'0.8'});
          <?php } ?>
        });
    </script>
```